# Divs just won't align horizontally

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get 3 divs to align horizontally in my footer. I've tried a bunch of different solutions and have been able to get them very close, but they're just not perfectly aligned.

As of right now, the "biofreeze" element is a bit too high up and the "rocktape" element slightly overlaps the "graston" element. The "graston" element is pretty much exactly where I want it, though.

Playing around with the margins also doesn't seem to work too well.

Here's the code:

```css
#sponsors {
  width: 100% vertical-align: top !important;
}
#biofreeze {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}
#graston {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}
#rocktape {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div id="sponsors">
  <div id="biofreeze">
    <a href="http://www.biofreeze.com/">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="graston">
    <a href="http://www.grastontechnique.com/home">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="rocktape">
    <a href="http://www.rocktape.com/">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are going to need to link to the actual images, the code you have provided does not show the issue you are describing.

Comment: I'm building this website locally, so I can't link to it.

Comment: Images aren't shown. And floated elements are always horizontally aligned to top. Maybe padding inside them or big images causing problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider using `inline-block` in this case for different `height`s. Also, `vertical-align` won't work for `float`ed elements. Plus, there's no `;` before `vertical-align`, so it won't even affect.

```css
#biofreeze,
#graston,
#rocktape {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="sponsors">
  <div id="biofreeze">
    <a href="http://www.biofreeze.com/">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
    </a>
  </div><div id="graston">
    <a href="http://www.grastontechnique.com/home">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x275" />
    </a>
  </div><div id="rocktape">
    <a href="http://www.rocktape.com/">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or if you want all these to be aligned middle, you can use `vertical-align: middle` instead:

```css
#biofreeze,
#graston,
#rocktape {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="sponsors">
  <div id="biofreeze">
    <a href="http://www.biofreeze.com/">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
    </a>
  </div><div id="graston">
    <a href="http://www.grastontechnique.com/home">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x275" />
    </a>
  </div><div id="rocktape">
    <a href="http://www.rocktape.com/">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your second suggestion with vertical-align: middle worked to align them horizontally, but "rocktape" was still overlapping "graston". So I changed the "rocktape" width to 10% and margin-left to 60px and it looks great now in my browser. On mobile is a different story.. but I'll sort that out later. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

100% working code

```css
#sponsors {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top !important;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:2px solid grey;
}


#biofreeze{
height:250px;
background-color:#07c;
}

#graston{
height:300px;
background-color:#cc5600;
}

#rocktape{
height:100px;
background-color:#45ba5b;
}


#biofreeze,#graston,#rocktape {
  display:inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div id="sponsors">
  <div id="biofreeze">
    Height:250px;
  </div>
  <div id="graston">
    Height:300px;
  </div>
  <div id="rocktape">
    Height:100px;
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: They are not aligning middle on Chrome 50 on Windows 10.

Comment: Lemme tell you again. Removing the float, will align middle, but you will face the issues like third content coming down. Again, your answer is wrong.